# Using angular-recursion to display nested structure on the html table

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I am trying to display a nested tree structure using html table ( I am using smart-table for sorting/searching convenience) and angularJS. All I am trying to do is repeatedly add  element to display all the nodes listed in the nested structure recursively. To achieve this I have written a directive and calling it recursively using angular-recursion module. But during the recursion, the element  is being added under the parent  element. Due to this the rows () are not being added for deeper nodes[child32 in the example]. Only level 0 and level 1 nodes are shown.

Please refer to [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CwisAWNvAGU1lgiKJVOS?p=preview) code here.

One reason could be that a  under another  doesn't mean anything and could be neglected. I am not able to figure out a way to avoid that.

```
app.directive("nodeTree", function(RecursionHelper, $compile) {
return {
    restrict: "AE",
    controller: 'View1Ctrl',
    template:
    '<tr ng-show=node.childrenVisible>'+
        '<td class="padding node.level"><i class="glyphicon" ng-class="node.type1" ng-click="iconClick(node)"></i> {{node.name1}} </td>' +
        '<td>{{node.size1 | bytes}}</td>' +
        '<td>{{node.date1 | date:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"}}</td>' +
        '<td>{{node.state}}</td>' +
        '<td class="padding node.level"><i class="glyphicon" ng-class="node.type2" ng-click="iconClick(node)"></i> {{node.name2}} </td>' +
        '<td>{{node.size2 | bytes}}</td>' +
        '<td>{{node.date2 | date:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"}}</td>' +
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr node-tree ng-show=node.childrenVisible ng-repeat="node in node.nodes"></tr>',
    compile: function(element) {
        return RecursionHelper.compile(element, function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn){

            scope.iconClick = function(node){
                //node.childrenVisible = !node.childrenVisible;
                node.nodes.forEach(function(entry){
                        entry.childrenVisible = !entry.childrenVisible;
                });
                node.type2 =  (node.type2 == "glyphicon-folder-close" || node.type2 == "glyphicon-folder-open")? (node.type2 == "glyphicon-folder-close" ? "glyphicon-folder-open" : "glyphicon-folder-close") : ((node.type2 == "glyphicon-menu-right")? "glyphicon-menu-right": "") ;
                node.type1 =  (node.type1 == "glyphicon-folder-close" || node.type1 == "glyphicon-folder-open") ? (node.type1 == "glyphicon-folder-close" ? "glyphicon-folder-open" : "glyphicon-folder-close") : ((node.type2 == "glyphicon-menu-right")? "glyphicon-menu-right": "");
            };
        });
    }
};
```

});

Following is how I have called this directive:

```
<table st-table="treeData" class="table" id="main_table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"><input st-search="name1" class="input-sm form-control" placeholder="global search ..." type="search"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th st-sort="name1" style="width:auto">Name</th>
                    <th st-sort="size1" style="width:auto">Size</th>
                    <th st-sort="date1" style="width:auto">Last Modified</th>
                    <th st-sort="state" style="width:auto">State</th>
                    <th st-sort="name2" style="width:auto">Name</th>
                    <th st-sort="size2" style="width:auto">Size</th>
                    <th st-sort="date2" style="width:auto">Last Modified</th>
                </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody node-tree ng-repeat="node in treeData"></tbody>
            </table>
```

I am a beginner to JS, AngularJS and frontend. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Never used angular-recursion, but recursive templates are fairly easy to build in angular, you could have a look at: https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-tree